# How can I apply the Photoshop filter Pixelate > Crystallize to an image programmatically?

Tags: php, api, unity-game-engine, photoshop, image-manipulation

I need to apply crystallized pixels filter to an image via some API or library. This effect should look like this:

[image: image_example]

So this is not the usual pixel effect, the pixels are not square shaped.

Is there any API I can use? I have been looking for this but I am a bit lost.

Comment: Crystalize is an image processing algo that can be implemented in many different languages.  I would suggest picking a preferred tech stack and narrowing your question.  e.g. I found a Scala implementation that probably wouldn't help in a few minutes of Googling...

Answer (score 4):

Oops, I just noticed you tagged with PHP not Python - sorry! I'll leave it for now as reference and may do a PHP version another day.

I had a quick attempt at this and it works well enough:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy
import random
import math
import sys
from PIL import Image

def crystallize(im, cnt):
    # Make output image same size
    res = np.zeros_like(im)
    h, w = im.shape[:2]
    # Generate some randomly placed crystal centres
    nx = np.random.randint(0,w,cnt,dtype=np.uint16)
    ny = np.random.randint(0,h,cnt,dtype=np.uint16)
    # Pick up colours at those locations from source image
    sRGB = []
    for i in range(cnt):
        sRGB.append(im[ny[i],nx[i]])

    # Iterate over image
    for y in range(h):
        for x in range(w):
            # Find nearest crystal centre...
            dmin = sys.float_info.max
            for i in range(cnt):
                d = (y-ny[i])*(y-ny[i]) + (x-nx[i])*(x-nx[i])
                if d < dmin:
                    dmin = d
                    j = i
            # ... and copy colour of original image to result
            res[y,x,:] = sRGB[j]
    return res

# Open image, crystallize and save
im  = Image.open('duck.jpg')
res = crystallize(np.array(im),200)
Image.fromarray(res).save('result.png')
```

It turns this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

or this if you go for 500 crystals:

[image]

---

The speed can probably be improved by reducing to 256 colours and a palletised image, finding the nearest colour for each and then simply looking them up in a LUT. Maybe a job for a rainy day...

---

**Keywords**: Python, voronoi, crystal, crystallize, Photoshop, filter, image, image processing, Numpy, PIL, Pillow.

Comment: Amazing answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to apply Crystallize filter with Photoshop api in Python, taken from example https://github.com/lohriialo/photoshop-scripting-python/blob/master/EmbossAction.py

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch, GetActiveObject

app = GetActiveObject("Photoshop.Application")
fileName = "C:\Github\Test.psd"
docRef = app.Open(fileName)

docRef.ActiveLayer = docRef.ArtLayers.Item(1)

def applyCrystallize(cellSize):
    cellSizeID = app.CharIDToTypeID("ClSz")
    eventCrystallizeID = app.CharIDToTypeID("Crst")
    filterDescriptor = Dispatch('Photoshop.ActionDescriptor')
    filterDescriptor.PutInteger(cellSizeID, cellSize)
    app.ExecuteAction(eventCrystallizeID, filterDescriptor)

applyCrystallize(25)
```